# Create binaries using golang inside docker container

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to create binaries (cross platform) using go build inside a container. When I tried in my system, it compiled faster. When I tried the same inside the docker container it's taking too long(comparatively 10 times slower). This statement may not be detailed enough about my problem. But this is what I'm trying to do.

my code snippet:

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c","CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o sample")
cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(), []string{"CGO_ENABLED=0", "GOOS=linux","GOARCH=amd64"}...)
cmd.Dir = filepath.Join(rulePath, taskName)
_, err := cmd.Output()
```

As you can see, I passed the go envs as arguments as well as env's.  What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are starting a new container for every build you are likely missing the build cache. See GOCACHE and GOMODCACHE in `go env` and `go help environment`. Adding the `-x` flag will show you what Go is doing, exactly. Compare this for the host and container.

Comment: Also depending on your precise setup filesystem activities can be slower inside a container. And of course compiling code can involve a lot of reading and writing of files.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, try to set "CGO_ENABLED=1".
If there are any questions, you can let me know.